# php select from 2 tables and order by

Tags: php

i have 2 tables:
1st table is called maxlift with 1 column called, exercise
2nd table is called workout with 5 columns called, exercise, sets, reps, weight, date

i want display the highest weight for each exercise where exercise in both tables is the same.
i am using:

```
`SELECT *
FROM workout, maxlift 
WHERE workout.exercise = maxlift.exercise
GROUP BY maxlift.exercise
ORDER BY workout.weight desc`
```

the problem i have is the weight displayed is not the highest weight from table workout.

thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the data type of weight?

Comment: weight is varchar 255(if thats what you mean, sorry i am new to this).it is entered just as numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function `max()` for this.

```
SELECT workout.exercise, max(weight) as weight 
FROM workout, maxlift 
WHERE workout.exercise=maxlift.exercise
GROUP BY workout.exercise;
```

Now, you basically group by `exercise` and find the maximum weight for each such group using the `max()` function. You can alias your selected column using `column_name as alias`.

Comment: using your code gives me error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in. Thanks

Comment: can u post the php code that you are using to run the query ? @chocman

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
    FROM workout, maxlift 
    WHERE workout.exercise = maxlift.exercise
    GROUP BY maxlift.exercise
    ORDER BY workout.weight desc
    ;")
    ?>

Comment: after that i use while to create a table

Comment: hmm strange, i am getting either the lowest or second lowest weight not the highest. thanks for trying

Comment: That is exactly what i need, but when i use that code i cant echo $row['weight'].

Comment: Hi sanketh, could i ask you if i wanted add an extra column to both tables called username and select from table where workout.exercise=maxlift.exercise AND workout.username=maxlift.username, should that work, how would the code look? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT *
FROM workout, maxlift 
WHERE workout.exercise = maxlift.exercise
ORDER BY workout.weight desc`
```

use this by removing group by and let me know about it

Comment: removing group by shows all the weights from each exercise in workout, starting with the highest listing each exercise multiple times. i would each exercise listed only once. Thanks